# Javascript short circuiting in if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, short-circuiting

I am confused about the below if statement code. Not sure what it is exactly doing

```
if (this.props.filterURL && nextProps.filterURL !== this.props.filterURL) {}
```

Can someone please help me to understand this?

Is it a short-circuiting in if statement:
i.e

1- if first this.props.filterURL from left side is false then it will return false. 2- if first this.props.filterURL has a value then it will return true and the second variable nextProps.filterURL will be compared to this.props.filterURL on the right most of the statement?

Comment: What you have said is correct. First it checks the value this.props.filterURL to be true. If that fails it returns false, if that is true then only it will check the condition  nextProps.filterURL !== this.props.filterURL

Comment: You have summarized it accurately. The fact that the left operand of the expression being false would make the whole expression false is, indeed, short-circuiting.

Comment: if the this.props.filterUrl is truthy it will proceed to check if is not equal to nextProps.filterUrl and if the entire thing is true then executes the enclosed code.

Comment: Note that the first `this.props.filterURL` is checking for a *truthy* value, not for `true` specifically. If the property is not defined that is *falsy*, but if the value is `null` or `0` or an empty string those are all falsy too.

Comment: This is well documented in places like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators, and in numerous posts here on SO. It is also trivially easy to verify in the console or a sandbox/REPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of AND operator it evaluates the second expression only if the first one is true.

In your case,

```
if (this.props.filterURL && nextProps.filterURL !== this.props.filterURL) {}
```

can be interpreted as `if(expr1 && expr2)`
where `expr1= this.props.filterURL` and `expr2 = nextProps.filterURL !== this.props.filterURL`

for first expression `expr1` it evaluates whether it is not **null or undefined**...

for the second expression `expr2` **nextProps.filterURL !== this.props.filterURL** it checks both the value and data type. So for example if you have both value as same 1234 but for one it is of type String and for another it is for number, this condition would be true.

Comment: *only if the first one is true* This is incorrect. *evaluates whether it is not null or undefined*. This is also incorrect.

Comment: In Browser JS console please run the below code and see what it the O/P is, then set number to null or undefined and run the if block alone...
var number ="number";
if(number)
{
console.log("hello");
}

Answer (score 1):

**Notes :**

- This short-circuiting is good for the performance, as it allows significant bits of calculations to be skipped.
- The AND operator **`(&&)`** returns true if both expressions are true, otherwise it returns false.

[image]

**DEMO**

```js
var x = 1;
var y = 5;

if (x > 0 && y < 6) { console.log(x) }; // true

if(x > 1 && y < 6) { console.log(x) }; // false
```

- As suggested by [**nnnnnn**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) in his comment, `the first this.props.filterURL is checking for a truthy value, not for true specifically. If the property is not defined that is falsy, but if the value is null or 0 or an empty string those are all falsy too.`